# C# State Machine state change delegation

Tags: c#, .net, state-machine, fsm

I have been trying to build my own generic state machine but I can't figure out a way to tie state changes with events.

For now my generic implementation looks like this:

```
public interface IStateRoot
{

}
public interface IState<T> where T: IStateRoot
{

}

public abstract class State<T> : IState<T> where T: IStateRoot
{
    public delegate void OnChange(IState<T> state);
    OnChange OnStateChange;

    public void Invoke()
    {
        OnStateChange?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
public class FSM<T> where T: IStateRoot
{
    public delegate void TransitionDelegate<K>(IState<K> state) where K: T;
    public Dictionary<Type, TransitionDelegate<T>> Transitions;
    public State<T> State { get; set; }
    public FSM()
    {
        Transitions = new Dictionary<Type, TransitionDelegate<T>>();
    }
    public FSM(State<T> init)
    {
        Transition(init);
    }

    public void Transition<K>(K nextState) where K : State<T>
    {
        if (Transitions.TryGetValue(typeof(K), out var value))
        {
            value?.Invoke(nextState);
        }
        State = nextState;
    }

    public void OnTransition<K>(State<K>.OnChange action) where K : T
    {
        if (Transitions.TryGetValue(typeof(K), out var value))
        {
            value += action;
            return;
        }

        Transitions.Add(typeof(K), action);
    }

}
```

In a perfect world I would like to be able to create my own `StateRoot` and his `States` like this

```
 public class MyState : IStateRoot
{
    public class InitState : State<MyState> { }

    public class EndState : State<MyState> { }

}
```

And then use it like this

```
 public class StateListener
{
    public FSM<MyState> StateMachine;

    public StateListener()
    {
        StateMachine = new FSM<MyState>();
        StateMachine.OnTransition<MyState.InitState>(OnInit);
        StateMachine.OnTransition<MyState.EndState>(OnEndState);
        StateMachine.Transition(new MyState.InitState());
    }

    public void OnEndState(MyState.EndState state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EndState");
    } 

    public void OnInit(MyState.InitState state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StartState");
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem with hooking generic methods to `OnTransition`.

The issue I'm having is that I can't convert from `State<K>.OnChange` to `FSM<T>.TransitionDelegate<K>` in OnTransitionMethod. I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: What kind of problem? Do you get an error? You have thrown all this code... Could you refactor so that we can reproduce your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think the question has all the code needed for reproduction, I just tried to copy and paste it into new solution.

Comment: You don't need all that code to create a state machine. You can use pattern matching and switch expressions to create a state machine with just a single line per transition, in a single method. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Check [Changing State with the Switch expression](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2019/09/03/swtichexpression/). F# developers have been having fun at C# due to the verbose code needed to specify a FSM [compared to F#](https://www.marccostello.com/simple-state-machines-in-f/) but now we can write the same kind of code

Comment: I'd like to ommit using Enums and switch statement. I'm trying to make use of classes so I can have extra properties in States. This would also allow me to easily manage possible states. If you look at StateListener you can see how neat and tidy it looks in usage.

Comment: Take a look at [appccelerate/statemachine](https://github.com/appccelerate/statemachine). It is an open source c# library which does what you are looking for you and you can use it to get some ideas. [Stateless](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless) is another open source library where you can get some good ideas.